# How to Create a Genexus Server User With a password to change in first login

Tags: genexus

Is there a way to create a user in Genexus Server, but after a create when a user login on Genexus ask to change his password ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ealmeida's answer. If your scenario is that you want to create a new user with a random password, and force the user to change it, I'd suggest requesting the user to follow the [I forgot my password](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?26373,HowTo%3A%20Using%20the%20%27I%20forgot%20my%20password%27%20option) flow after the user is created.
In order to be able to use this option, the created user must have an associated email account, and the SMTP settings must be properly configured in the GXserver instance.

Comment: Good.But every time i Upgrade my Genexus i need to make this again ? because in genexus ide somethimes support say change genexus.config but every single upgrade i lost my customization.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The suggestion about the GXserver user password, you have to do it only once (or once per new user) when you create the account in your GXserver.
For the customizations lost in Genexus.exe.config, you can set most of those customizations in the Environmeng.config file under your use account profile, and those are preserved when updating GeneXus between upgrades. The Environment.config file is in `%AppData%\GeneXus\GeneXus\18\Environment.config`. The `18` in the previous path is the GeneXus version, which changes on each major release.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to change the Genexus Server password from the GeneXus IDE.

In our case, what we do is create the user with a strong password and ask him (via email) to connect to the web console to change it. It is not a foolproof method, but it works if there are few new users.

Comment: Now it doesn't, but if the person who makes Genexus used the tool, they would see a lot of failures and small problems that interfere with their daily work.